# Random sequence of execution of statements when using async await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a very simple program as shown below.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Task task = DemoCompletedAsync();

            MessageBox.Show("Method returned");            
            MessageBox.Show("Exiting .....");
        }

        static async Task<string> DemoCompletedAsync()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Before first await");

            await Task.Run(() => GetID());

            MessageBox.Show("After first await");

            return "Demo";
        }

        public static int GetID()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

While running the program without debug mode the message boxes appear in correct sequence.
i.e.
"Before first await"
"Method returned"
"Exiting ....."
"After first await"

But while debugging the statement get executed in random manner somehow switching to and forth between `MainWindow()` and `DemoCompletedAsync`
The message boxed appear in below manner:
"Before first await"  --- from `DemoCompletedAsync`
"Method returned"     --- from `MainWWindow`
"After first await"   --- from `DemoCompletedAsync`
"Exiting ....."      --- from `MainWindow`

As per theory, the use of `async` keyword in the method name tells the compiler that this method will be awaiting on an asynchronous operation using the await keyword and as soon as the await keyword is encountered, the control would pass on to the **calling code**. However, the asynchronous operation signified by the await keyword would continue executing. Once the asynchronous operation is over, **rest of the method is executed**. So why I am getting this strange behavior such as some statements get executed from `MainWindow` and some from `DemoCompletedAsync` switching to and forth from each other. I have also observed one more problem related to message boxes. MessageBox.Show is modal dialog box. The second one should not appear until the first closes. But in the case of given program, I actually get two message boxes simultaneously as the control switches between `MainWindow` and `DemoCompletedAsync`.

Comment: The message box "Task completed" is shown at the point that the task has just been created, but has not been awaited. So the message is deceptive. I suggest to include the `task.Status` in the message.

Comment: You aren't actually awaiting the task because your main method doesn't await it so the messages will show immediately, what are you actually trying to do? It's this just an experiment with tasks?

Comment: @Charleh
Yes, I am experimenting with tasks.  Yes the messages will be shown immediately. But they should be shown in an order i.e. either both the messages from the ```MainWindow``` or a message from ```DemoCompletedAysnc```. Why are some messages shown from ```MainWindow``` then from ```DemoCompletedAsync``` and again from ```MainWindow```. The messages from the ```MainWindow``` should be shown in sequence.

Answer (score 4):

All these happened due to this line:

```
Task task = DemoCompletedAsync();
```

You didn't await this task, so when instruction pointer reached to real Thread (here `Task.Run(() => GetID());`) next lines executed immediately. So next line that executed could be one of `MessageBox.Show("Method returned");` or `MessageBox.Show("After first await");` randomely!

But the point here is that you can't await this task because you're in constructor and it can't be async. Also you can't wait this task like `DemoCompletedAsync().Wait()` because you're in `Synchronization Context` and a deadlock will occur.

So you should call it this way:

```
DemoCompletedAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and use `Dispatcher.Invoke` in `DemoCompletedAsync` method for GUI actions

Comment: GetResult should be avoided. ConfigureAwait is rarely necessary.

Comment: You should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when you don't want to return to the UI thread. It should be used for example in a Repository or something not UI related.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: You're right Henk. As far as we can we should avoid blocking threads but I tried to explain senarios and answer question based on its current structure.  Also it's always recommended to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for preventing deadlocks. +1 for your answer that mentioned restructuring to `Form_Load` event

Comment: @Michael: Please refer to my above comment. Also see last line in my answer that is a solution to what you mentioned about UI

Comment: @Arman, my comment was to @HenkHolterman comment. But `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't to prevent deadlocks. I agree that it can do that, but it shouldn't just be put all over the place. You need to know what it does and therefore you need to know about `Context`. `ConfigureAwait` only applies if you are actually going to do an `await`. GetAwaiter` doesn't count. If you are on a UI thread and have an `await` statement you will typical return to the UI thread after the `await`. If the Task that you await has `ConfigureAwait(false)` it will return on another context, probably a new thread.

Comment: @Michael: Of course if we CAN `await` somewhere `ConfigureAwait` has no benefit but here in constructor we had no choice to use await so it was vital there. also I agree with you about your last line and for that reason I used `Dispatcher.Invoke` for UI related actions to ensure they always run in `UI thread`